# Why isn't my function being called in Java?

Tags: java

I'm new to java, and trying to learn on my own. I'm coming from a background in C++. Any help would be much appreciated. FibonacciSeq() isn't being called in my main and I'm unsure why. I made the method to accept the beginning integer (0) in a fibonacci sequence and from there recurse filling a vector with each value. The function should end when the vector has 9 elements.

```
public class Fibonacci 
{
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Vector<Integer> fibonacciVect = new Vector<Integer>(0);
    static int second;
    static int newFirst;
    static int fibIn = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    System.out.print("Here comes the Fibonacci, watch out!");   

    fibonacciSeq(fibIn);

    System.out.print("Values in Fibonacci Vector:");
    for (int i = 0; i < fibonacciVect.size(); i++)
        {
        System.out.print(fibonacciVect.elementAt(i));
        }

    System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void fibonacciSeq(int first)
    {
        if (first == 0)
        {
            second = 1;
            fibonacciVect.addElement(0);
            fibonacciVect.addElement(1);
            newFirst = first + second;
            fibonacciSeq(newFirst);
        }

        if (fibonacciVect.size() == 9)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else
        {
            newFirst = first + second;
            fibonacciVect.addElement(newFirst);
            second = first;
            fibonacciSeq(newFirst);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not use `Vector` and `System.exit`, if you have just started learning Java.

Comment: `System.exit(0)` terminates your program.

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner, you can instead replace you System.exit(0) by return

```
if (fibonacciVect.size() == 9)
    {
        return;
    }
```

Also, please remove the other System.exit(0) too.
Your code should work now.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Kindly upvote and accept please if it helped, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Because you coded a System.Exit() at the point that you reach the 9th recursion.
That causes yout program to finish. You can use a return statement instead.